# How to trigger click event / call a function repeatly when a button is clicked and hold

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6

So, I'm a begineer in JS and tryning figure out this problem. I have this HTML and JS

```js
function incrementValue()
{
    var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('number').value, 10);
    value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
    value++;
    document.getElementById('number').value = value;
}
```

```html
<form>
   <input type="text" id="number" value="0"/>
   <input type="button" onclick="incrementValue()" value="Increment Value" />
</form>
```

If you click it increments, simple. Now I want the button to be such that If I click on the button and hold, the number keeps increasing automaticaly until I let go the button. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should handle the `mousedown` and `mouseup` event of the button.

on `mousedown`, start a timer (setInterval) to call incrementValue periodly. on `mouseup`, stop the timer.

```js
function incrementValue()
{
    var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('number').value, 10);
    value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
    value++;
    document.getElementById('number').value = value;
}

var timer;
function start() {
    timer = setInterval(incrementValue, 100);
}
function stop() {
    clearInterval(timer);
}
```

```html
<form>
   <input type="text" id="number" value="0"/>
   <input type="button" onmousedown="start()" onmouseup="stop()" onmouseleave="stop()" value="Increment Value" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `mousedown` and `mouseup` events instead of `click` events.

Start an interval on `mousedown`, and clear it on `mouseup`.

You might want to add some checks for `mouseout` in case the mouse is moved while the the button is held down.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:**

You bind the event [onmousedown](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmousedown.asp) to the button and make it execute [setInterval()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) to increment your value at your desired speed.

**Step 2:**

You bind the event [onmouseup](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseup.asp) to the button that when the user releases the hold, it will execute [clearInterval()](http://clearInterval()) to stop the interval.

Answer (score 0):

I have the solution for you buy using on mousedown event, I will use Jquery:
HTMl

```
<button>My Button</button>
<div> </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var number = 0;
var isMouseDown = false;
$('button').mousedown(function(){
  isMouseDown = true;
  if(isMouseDown){
    var addNumber = setInterval(function(){
    number++;
    $('div').html(number) ;
  }, 100)
  }
  $('html').mouseup(function(){
    isMouseDown = false;
    clearInterval(addNumber)
  })
})
```